# White screen on emulator and device because of es6 code not transpiled android 5.1.1

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, es6-modules, android-5.1.1-lollipop, es5-shim

I'm doing an ionic project using cordova for an android app, while deploying on android version 5.1 , i'm getting  some syntax erros :

- Uncaught Syntax error : unexpected token
- Uncaught Syntax error : WebpackJsonp not defined

I changed the target of the compiler options in the tsconfig.json file  from es5 to  es6 , now I've got new errors
[image]

Comment: you found some solution?